# Modify bibliography style like journal name, comma and title

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apacite

i want to do some modify on my bibliography style.

- Titles' first letters are not listing like in the
  literature.bib. I want to show like in the bib file.

> True: Permanent Scatterers in SAR Interferometry
>      False:Permanent scatterers in sar interferometry

- I want the journal names to be underlined and not Italic.

> True: IEEE Transactions on Geoscience and Remote Sensing (I could
>   not underlined.(: )    False: *IEEE Transactions on Geoscience and
>   Remote Sensing*

- I want the remove comma between 1. and 2. names, 2. and 3. names, ...

> True:
>
> ```
>    Ferretti, A., Prati, C. ve Rocca, F. 2001.
>
>    Ferretti, A., Prati, C., Rocca, F. ve Zadı, Y. 2001.
>
>    Frattini, P., Crosta, G. B. ve Allievi, J. 2013.
>
>    Zadı, Y. ve Isoyad, I. 2009.
> ```
>
> False:
>
> ```
>       Ferretti, A., Prati, C., ve Rocca, F. 2001.
>
>       Ferretti, A., Prati, C., Rocca, F., ve Zadı, Y. 2001.
>
>       Frattini, P., Crosta, G. B., ve Allievi, J. 2013.
>
>       Zadı, Y., ve Isoyad, I. 2009.
> ```

Thank you.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,top=30mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{apacite}
%%% Same fonts for URL
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}} % Make bibliography links the same 


% BIBLIOGRAPHY
%%% Bibliography line spacing
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
%%% Removing parentheses around year in bibliography
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\BBOP}{}
\renewcommand{\BBCP}{}

\renewcommand{\BBAA}{ve}
%\renewcommand{\BBAB}{} %What is?
%\renewcommand{\BAnd}{} %What is?
}

\renewcommand{\BOthers}{vd}

%%% Adding ":" character before page number in citations
\bibpunct[: ]{(}{)}{:}{a}{,}{~}
%........................................


\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} %son yükle



% BEGIN
\begin{document}

% CHAPTER 1
\chapter{GİRİŞ}
\citep{ferretti2001}, \citep{onlinedeneme}, \citet{frattini2013}, \citet{onlinedeneme}'e göre.
\lipsum[1-1]


% CHAPTER 2
% BIBLIOGRAPHY (Kaynaklar)
\renewcommand*\bibname{KAYNAKLAR}
\nocite{*} % Add all references within the .bib file
\phantomsection
\bibliographystyle{apacite}


\setlength{\bibsep}{1\itemsep}
\bibliography{literature}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

**literature.bib**

```
@article{ferretti2001,
  title     = {Permanent Scatterers in SAR Interferometry},
  author    = {Alessandro Ferretti and Claudio Prati and Fabio Rocca},
  journal   = {IEEE Transactions on Geoscience and Remote Sensing},
  number    = {1},
  volume    = {39},
  pages     = {8--20},
  year      = {2001},
  publisher = {IEEE-INST Electrical Electronics Engineers Inc},
  doi       = {10.1109/36.898661},
}
@article{frattini2013,
  title     = {Damage to Buildings in Large Slope Rock Instabilities
Monitored with the PSInSAR™ Technique},
  author    = {Paolo Frattini and Giovanni B. Crosta and Jacopo Allievi},
  journal   = {Remote Sensing},
  volume    = {5},
  pages     = {4753--4773},
  year      = {2013},
  publisher = {MDPI AG},
  doi       = {10.3390/rs5104753}, 
}
@online{onlinedeneme,
  title     = {Deneme Başlığı},
  author    = {Yazar Zadı and Iyazar Isoyad},
  year      = {2009},
  url       = {http://www.nytimes.com/},
  urldate   = {28 Ocak 2018}
}
@book{pye2010trashculture,
  author    = {John Doe},
  publisher = {Book Company},
  series    = {Cultural Interactions},
  title     = {Cultures of Amazons},
  year      = {2015},
}
```

Comment: Please consider asking only one question per question in the future. That makes your question easier to answer and more relevant for people with similar issues. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864

Comment: @moewe I asked in a title because of I thought my questions are related to each other. Thank you for warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**: simply enclose SAR by brackets:

```
title     = {Permanent Scatterers in {SAR} Interferometry},
```

and do the same for anything that should not ne lowercased, like `{A}mazons` or better `{Amazons}` according to moewe comment.

**Question 2**: If you don't want to hack the `.bst` style file, you can use this trick :

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\APACjournalVolNumPages}{\Bem}{\uline}{}{}
```

This can be obtained by looking at the `.bbl` file produced by `BibTeX`: the journal is formated bith the command `\APACjournalVolNumPages`; with

```
\meaning\APACjournalVolNumPages
\meaning\Bem
```

in the document, you see that the italicization is performed by`\Bem`;
Finally, using `\patchcmd` provided by `etoolbox` you replace it by `\uline` provided by `ulem.`

**Question 3**:Simply redefine the macro:

```
\renewcommand{\BCBL}{}
```

Comment: +1, but I'd prefer `{Amazons}` over `{A}mazons` since the latter could destroy the kerning between `A` and `m`. One may also want to load `ulem`  with the `normalem` option.

Comment: @moewe, I agree to both comments, thank you. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Jhor Thank you, it is working good. In addition, volume number, book title, online title and misc title are italic. How can i make them regular (non italic) too?

Comment: On my computer, the title of the fictitious book on Amazons, and the volume numbers are underlined too. If something is not to your taste, apply the same approach described in my answer : open the ``.bbl`` file, identify the command which produces the unwanted result, ask  LaTeX  to print its ``\meaning``, and ``\patchcmd`` it according to your idea. By the way, the command to get 'regular' shape is ``\textnormal``.

Comment: Thank you @jhor. I am using overleaf and found the .bbl file as you say. \textnormal did not work. Because of moewe's warning about forum usage, i will open a new title about this specific matter. Best wishes.